# How to save a LateX rendered image (via Latexify) to disk in png in Julia

Tags: julia, png

I am using Julia.
I used Latexitfy to generate an image from a model equations using the following code:

```
Latexify.latexify(model_equations) |> render
```

Now I'd like to export that image generated to save it on my disk.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can render to a target [MIME type](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.Multimedia.MIME) using the second argument to `render`. The documentation provides [a useful example](https://korsbo.github.io/Latexify.jl/stable/#External-rendering):

```
latexify(:(x/y)) |> s -> render(s, MIME("image/png"))
```

Breaking down this one-liner:

```
l = latexify(:(x/y))  # convert the fraction x/y to LaTeX text
m = MIME("image/png") # set up a MIME type target of PNG (can also be "image/svg")
render(l, m)          # save the rendered LaTeX to a temporary PNG and try to display it
```

The `render` function [takes several keyword arguments](https://github.com/korsbo/Latexify.jl/blob/956eccb5982244649087c909f2895400b03d6cb5/src/utils.jl#L152) that are not well documented. If you want to write the rendered LaTeX to a file with a specific name, pass the `name` argument. Note that the extension `.png` will be added automatically:

```
render(l, m, name="./my_file_name")
```

Note two things about the file name:

1. The name does not have a ".png" extension. The package will add the appropriate extension itself. It is also likely to create other files in the same directory that are byproducts of compiling a latex document, like `my_file_name.tex`, `my_file_name.aux`, `my_file_name.log`, and `my_file_name.pdf`.
2. The name includes a directory. [Because of a bug in the package that was fixed shortly after this post](https://github.com/korsbo/Latexify.jl/issues/256), if you did not include a directory name in the file name, the method would throw `ERROR: IOError: cd(""): no such file or directory (ENOENT)`. *This has been fixed as of Latexify v0.15.19.*

The method call with the `name` argument will still attempt to display the image. If you do not want the image to be displayed, pass `false` to the `open` argument:

```
render(l, m, name="./my_file_name", open=false)
```

Comment: Thank you. The 3rd line you provided gives me an error when I give a file name. 
In the end, it creates a my_file_name.png.tex which is a tex file and not a png...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It looks like there is a bug in the package that requires a path with a directory name.